# How to place private folder on another server?

Tags: files

I am designing a file store with Drupal 7. The server provider told me that I am not allowed to put the files in the current server and I have to purchase a download server beside the current server.
All the files that can be downloaded via users must be placed over a separate download server and the rest of the scripts must be placed in a simple PHP server.

Is this possible, With Drupal?

I am selling files via commerce store and commerce file. all of the files are located in a private folder. users that pay the cost of files are able to download purchased files for a limited period of time, while others and anonymous are not allowed.

Now I have to put the private folder into a download-only host separated from current host.

I found some suggestion such as hosting files on the file server and copy the needed file from file server to the PHP server in order to give the download link to users.
I must say that the PHP server doesn't allow me to copy files from the file server, and all content of the *files* folder must be hosted in a file server.

Comment: I trued to use Storage API module. I could use ftp service bur I don't know how can I use Storage API for private files. In this module description it is written access for commerce but I don't know how can I use it.

Comment: I doubt that this is possible with a Vanilla Drupal. I guess you have to start to build something custom on your own.

Comment: It is possible to do with sym. links. It is possible to make the files directory a symbolic link to some mount point (like a NFS mount). I think this is too broad and possibly off-topic to Drupal itself depending on further details.